# What's up with the Siberys dragonmark?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, eberron

1. Besides taking at least two levels in the prestige class heir of Siberys (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 80-2), is there another method of gaining a Siberys dragonmark?
2. For the purpose of meeting a feat's prerequisite, is a Siberys dragonmark a true dragonmark?

   The phrase *true dragonmark*—used in the prerequisites of feats such as Breath of Siberys (*Dragonmarked* 135)—is mentioned in the description of the feat Aberrant Dragonmark ("A
   character with one of the true dragonmarks (least, lesser, or greater) cannot select this feat") (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 47), but I hesitate to base another feat's prerequisite on a definition provided by another feat, especially when a Siberys dragonmark mandates a creature select a mark from among non-aberrant dragonmarks from which the creature gains its power.
3. Although a creature can't take *both* the feat Least Dragonmark *and* the feat Aberrant Dragonmark, can a creature take either of those feats *after* gaining a Siberys dragonmark? (Yes, that *is* a high-level character... and whether it's optimal that a character do so isn't the issue.)

#### Bonus Question

- Is there an official pronunciation for Siberys? Is it ***sigh**-ber-iss*? Is it *cy-**beer**-ee-iss*? Is it ***sigh**-ber-eyes*?

Comment: "sih-BEAR-is." As in, "Ze bear is coming at me so quickly, I should activate this dragonmark." (Actually, Keith Baker has said that variants are acceptable — even desirable — as regional dialects. "Cyre," for instance, is pronounced "See-ree" by Baker, but he accepts "Sire," "Seer," "Khai-er" and others as valid.)

Comment: @Jadasc While presumably completely unrelated (or is it?), that pronunciation aligns with the pronunciation of the very similar Daenerys and Viserys Targaryen in the HBO series.

Answer (score 5):

1. I am reasonably confident that the answer is no. In the fluff, Siberys Dragonmarks are rare and strange beasts indeed, almost-randomly appearing, in people who previously had no mark at all.

The one candidate that came to mind, the cataclysm mage of *Explorer’s Handbook*, does not do so. Its Dragonmark Secret allows a 10th-level cataclysm mage to manifest any least, lesser, or greater dragonmark they choose, but even they cannot control Siberys marks.

2. By fluff, certainly. *Dragonmarked* discusses them in its introduction to dragonmarks, as just another level of dragonmark, and though many places refer to only least, lesser, and greater marks – due to their being far more common – Siberys marks should still qualify for feats and prestige classes as would any other mark.

I would also recommend allowing them to qualify for things that specify the Least Dragonmark feat – as this is effectively shorthand for “having a true dragonmark,” typically used when a specific mark is required. The only place I would balk would be things that specifically rely on the powers of a specific mark level – *Dragonmarked*’s black dog prestige class makes no sense if you lack the spell-like abilities of the Least Dragonmark of Hospitality, since it expands on those abilities.

But overall it seems certain to me that “true dragonmark” is meant only to contrast with aberrant marks. This is definitely how the fluff refers to it. Unfortunately, I cannot find a mechanical statement to this effect.

3. Less clear, both mechanically and fluff-wise, but I would allow it. My basis is the particular wording in the Heir of Siberys requirements:

> A character who has the Aberrant Dragonmark, Least Dragonmark, Lesser Dragonmark, or Greater Dragonmark feat **cannot enter** this prestige class. Also, **once a character has any levels in this class**, he can’t adopt the dragonmark heir prestige class.

It specifically refers to *entering* the class with those feats, while the bit about dragonmark heir specifies that you cannot ever enter it once you have heir of Siberys levels.

Also, RAW, the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* specifies that prestige class requirements must be met only to take the first level of a prestige class. No general rule specifies that requirements must continue to be met, though *Complete Warrior* and *Complete Arcane* do specify this for their own classes in a way that seems to try to apply generally (but cannot, by errata rules, and also because to do so would break classes, e.g. dragon disciple).

Finally, possibly worth noting: 4e eliminated the requirement that heirs of Siberys not already hold a dragonmark. This certainly implies that there need not be a conflict between Siberys marks and their inferior brethren.

- I know Keith Baker defined how to pronounce “Cyre” ([“SEER-ee”](http://bossythecow.com/hdwt/2010/10/eberron-faq-1072010-pronunciation-the-planes-and-things-i-cant-answer/)), but I have found nothing definitive for “Siberys.” Personally I go with “sib-er-EES.” Note also, however, that the pronunciation of “Cyre” is stated to be a regional thing (and other variations are offered), which may also be true for “Siberys.”